# Get the public link of file in Google Drive

Tags: android, drive

I want to write an APP, which I can get the download link of file on my drive and send the download link to another device to download this file from my drive.

I use intent to get the `content uri` of file in `google drive`.
How can I turn this `uri` to `public link`?
Then, I want to send this `public link` to `another app` and `mp3 player`, so another app and mp3 player can download the file via public link.

I choose file like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

I think maybe I need to convert content uri to "fileid" as mentioned in Google Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file
How to get the fileid?

Comment: please post your existing code, it just makes it easier for everyone trying to help you to see what or how you've done something

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a technical issue. You just want to make a file public over google drive. If that's the issue you can use [this link](https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-make-my-google-drive-document-public).

NOTE: Please choose right option as per your need to make it public.

For do the same from Andriod app of drive use [this](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) link

[image]

Comment: I mean get the public link from file manager in APP, not from web.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and but If it's still not what you want to ask then just refream your question.
I think you just want to share a local file from your app private memory and with other apps but for this you have to copy/move that file to public memory.

Comment: There will no file on my phone, my APP just can browse the file name on Drive. After I choose the file, my APP will ask(send a download link) another device to download the file from drive which already has existed on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

1> Go to drive right click on the item you want to copy link of.

2> Click on Get sharable link and then i will automatically copy link to you keyboard.

3> And then share the click where ever you want.

[image: Click to see how]

Comment: I mean get the public link from file manager in APP, not from web.